# Is it possible to define a local function in a TSQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a complex expression calculating a value from a date that I have to use on multiple date columns.
Can I define a temporary local function in my query to avoid copy and pasting this expression. ?

like:

```
create MyLocalFunc(@ADate datetime) 
returns int as
begin
  blablabla
end

select
  MyLocalFunc(col1), col2, MyLocalFunc(col3), col4, MyLocalFunc(col5)
from
  mytable
```

As a workaround, I know I can do a `CREATE FUNCTION // DROP FUNCTION`, but I'd prefer avoid it.

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981451/can-i-create-a-one-time-use-function-in-a-script-or-stored-procedure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create a One-Time-Use Function in a Script or Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981451/can-i-create-a-one-time-use-function-in-a-script-or-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there is no way -- create/drop is the only choice.

Comment: This answer mentions a way in which it is possible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/981461/750216

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda the answer you linked to suggests the create/drop approach, which this answer here already mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server supports [anonymous blocks](http://shan-tech.blogspot.com/2007/11/running-procedural-queries-in-sql.html) by putting the query(ies) inside a BEGIN/END block, but I haven't been able to find an example where someone defined a function within it.  Oracle's had the functionality for a while...

Comment: Could you explain more about anonymous blocks in SQL Server? That link is broken and I can't find anything myself.