# Difference between #temptable and ##TempTable?

Tags: sql-server, temp

What is the difference between `#temptable` and `##TempTable` in SQL Server?

Answer (score 59):

`#table` refers to a *local* temporary table - visible to only the user who created it

`##table` refers to a *global* temporary table - visible to all users

Answer (score 38):

`#TempTables` aren't just local to the User, or connection.  They are local to the process that created them and any processes that the creating process spawns.  For example if I have the following:

```
Declare @strDynamicSQL as varchar(8000)

Set @strDynamicSQL = 'Select GetDate() As TheDate Into #TheDateTable'
Execute(@strDynamicSQL)

Select *
From #TheDateTable
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 7 Invalid object name
>   '#TheDateTable'.

But if I do:

```
Declare @strDynamicSQL as varchar(8000)

Create Table #TheDateTable (
    TheDate     DateTime
)

Set @strDynamicSQL = 'Insert Into #TheDateTable Select GetDate() As TheDate'
Execute(@strDynamicSQL)

Select *
From #TheDateTable
```

I get no errors.

In the first example the `Execute` statement happens in a spawned process.  Since the table is created in that process when it returns that process goes away.  And with the process the table is "bye-bye".

In the second example the table is created by the top level process.  It's then interacted with in the spawned process.  The table is available to the process that it was created in and any process it spawns.

`##tables` break this.  The process a `##` table is created in will be the controlling process.  The table will not get flagged for removal if this process is still alive even if there are no tasks against that process.  Once the process that the `##` table was created in goes away, the table is tagged for removal when the last task is executed against it.

Here is a simple way to see it.  `#` tables are available only in the scope of the process that it was created in.  `##` are available in the same way as any other table except that the existence comes and goes with the process it was created in.

Answer (score 13):

Local temporary tables are visible only to their creators during the same connection to an instance of SQL Server as when the tables were first created or referenced. Local temporary tables are deleted after the user disconnects from the instance of SQL Server. Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are created, and are deleted when all users that are referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server.

[Taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2920883/2064292)

[More on this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/local-and-global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server-2008/)

Answer (score 5):

simple way of testing `#localtable and ##globaltable`

Try this in a different SQL Query  Window

```
create table ##globaltemptable (id int )
go
insert into ##globaltemptable values (1)
go
select * from ##globaltemptable
```

Try this in a different SQL Query  Window

```
create table #localtemptable (id int )
go
insert into #localtemptable values (1)
go
select * from #localtemptable
```

Now if you run the select query for the table : #localtemptable in the global window syntax , you will get an error as follows :-

```
Invalid object name '#localtemptable'.
```

While you run the select query for the table : ##globaltemptable in any query window of the same session, you will get the query results return.

Answer (score 5):

"**#tempTable**" denotes **Local Temporary Tables**

- It starts with single hash value "#" as the prefix of the table name.
- A Local Temporary Table is only for the connection in which it was
  created. Each Local Temporary Table has a random value at the end of
  the table name.
- A Local Temporary Table is automatically dropped when    the existing
  connection is closed, or the user can explicitly drop it    with the
  following command "drop table #TempTable".
- If the Temporary    Table is created in a Stored Procedure then it is
  automatically    dropped on the completion of the Stored Procedure
  execution.
- You can    create a Local Temporary Table with the same name but in a
  different    connection, and it is stored with the same name along
  with various    random values.

"**##tempTable**" denotes **Global Temporary Tables**

- It starts with the single hash value "##" as the prefix of the table
  name and its name is always unique.
- There is no random number appended to the name.Global Temporary
  Tables are visible to all connections of SQL Server.
- Global Temporary Tables are only destroyed when the last connection
  referencing the table is closed (in which we have created the Global
  Temporary Table).
- You can access the Global Temporary Tables from all connections of
  SQL Server until the referencing connection is open.

Answer (score 0):

The table will be visible/available up until the process/connection that created it ends and only to the session that created it.

The table is global and will be available to everyone until the process/session that created it is ended.