# SQL - # used while creating a temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm just wondering why `#` was used while creating this temporary table.

```
create table **#tmp** ( 
  Things to wonder about
)
```

The query works perfectly fine with/without it.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That behavior is product specific.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011276/difference-between-temptable-and-temptable

Comment: In SQL server a single # needs to prefix the name of local temporary tables. If you omit it, you're actually creating a non temporary table.

Comment: CDBMS - Columnar database management system

Comment: @vc74 I see thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vc74 answered the question

In SQL server a single # needs to prefix the name of local temporary tables. If you omit it, you're actually creating a non temporary table. – vc 74