# inline user defined function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle12c

in oracle 12c it is possible to have an inline user defined function

```
WITH
  FUNCTION with_function(p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN p_id;
  END;
SELECT with_function(id)
FROM   t1
WHERE  rownum = 1
```

is there an equivalent in sql server?   I have been researching for awhile but can not seem to find an equivalent.

Comment: There isn't really.

Comment: You need to define a *bona fide* function.  There are no local functions, but there are "inline" table functions that tend to be more efficient than "non-inline" table functions.

Comment: Here is an answer which may give you what you want:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/981491/9395740

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I create a One-Time-Use Function in a Script or Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981451/can-i-create-a-one-time-use-function-in-a-script-or-stored-procedure)