# Repeat a code block in a stored procedure without retyping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a block of code that I want to use over and over in a stored procedure. This block of code will set a number of variables to blank (`''`). I would like to do this without having to copy/paste the entire code every time.

Long story short, I'm using one stored procedure to send many unique emails with various tables and formats etc.

I'm accomplishing this by declaring these variables at the start of the stored procedure:

```
/* declare HTML variables */
declare @htmlSTART nvarchar(max), @htmlEND nvarchar(max), @body nvarchar(max), @greeting nvarchar(max), @closing nvarchar(max), @subject nvarchar(max)
declare @recipients nvarchar(max), @profile_name nvarchar(max), @body_format nvarchar(max), @copy_recipients nvarchar(max), @blind_copy_recipients nvarchar(max)
declare @table_header_01 nvarchar(max), @paragragh_01 nvarchar(max), @HTML_table_01 nvarchar(MAX), @disclaimer_01 nvarchar(max)
declare @table_header_02 nvarchar(max), @paragragh_02 nvarchar(max), @HTML_table_02 nvarchar(MAX), @disclaimer_02 nvarchar(max)
declare @table_header_03 nvarchar(max), @paragragh_03 nvarchar(max), @HTML_table_03 nvarchar(MAX), @disclaimer_03 nvarchar(max)
declare @table_header_04 nvarchar(max), @paragragh_04 nvarchar(max), @HTML_table_04 nvarchar(MAX), @disclaimer_04 nvarchar(max)
```

The stored procedure then queries a bunch of data, creates a temporary master data table for the emails, recursively pulls each unique email address with a cursor, creates tables with html, and emails relevant data like so:

```
set @body =
    concat
        (
            @htmlSTART
            , @greeting
            , @paragragh_01, @table_header_01, @HTML_table_01
            , @paragragh_02, @table_header_02, @HTML_table_02
            , @paragragh_03, @table_header_03, @HTML_table_03
            , @paragragh_04, @table_header_04, @HTML_table_04
            , @closing
            , @disclaimer_01
            , @htmlEND
        )
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = @profile_name
    , @body = @body
    , @body_format = @body_format
    , @recipients = @recipients
    , @copy_recipients = @copy_recipients
    , @blind_copy_recipients = @blind_copy_recipients
    , @subject = @subject
```

At the start of each email section I am setting the variables to blank:

```
set @table_header_01 = '' set @paragragh_01 = '' set @HTML_table_01 = '' set @disclaimer_01 = ''
set @table_header_02 = '' set @paragragh_02 = '' set @HTML_table_02 = '' set @disclaimer_02 = ''
set @table_header_03 = '' set @paragragh_03 = '' set @HTML_table_03 = '' set @disclaimer_03 = ''
set @table_header_04 = '' set @paragragh_04 = '' set @HTML_table_04 = '' set @disclaimer_04 = ''
```

Rather than having to remember which tables etc to remove from `set @body =` for each email, I reset the variables each time because some of the emails will contain only one table (or none) and some will contain multiple tables. If the `@html_table` variables are blank it will not mess up the email, but removing the wrong ones from `set @body =` will mess it up when I `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`.

I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981451/can-i-create-a-one-time-use-function-in-a-script-or-stored-procedure) thread which talks about creating temp procedures and I tried dynamic SQL as well, but the dynamic SQL cannot set the variables from the outer scope as far as I can tell. It throws the error stating that the variables `@HTML_table_01` etc have not been declared.

Is there any way to repeatedly set all the variables to `''` without copy/pasting/typing it out each time? If there's a good method for this, I'm sure there's a multitude of other applications for said method other than my specific use case.

Comment: Typically you would just assign all the variables, instead of clearing them and _then_ assigning them.

Comment: I agree that's the typical method.  Usually I also just assign variables and use them as I need them.  In this case however, it benefits me a lot to set them to blank so as not to have to remove them from my ```set @body =``` which is used to ```sp_send_dbmail```.  In this specific case, it's much more error proof for me to set them all to blank before each section.

Comment: You should make it the responsibility of the code that populates each variable to also assign null to any unused ones - when you concat them, nulls are ignored.

Comment: Yes, actually I should set them to null instead of blank.  I tested with blank and it looked fine, but a null is still better for the concatenation.

Either way, I'd like to find a way (if possible) to quickly reuse the code.  And, also either way, I will change it to set them to null instead of blank.

Thank you.

Comment: Dirty hacks are possible, eg using `goto` - you *could* have your variable init section and jump to it with *goto* and have another variable to store a value to determine where to then jump back to. But just thinking about it makes my blood run cold; t-sql is not like a typical imperative language - if you need to repeat a block of variable assignments, then so be it; you could probably re-engineer this though to use a temp table which you can just truncate and repopulate.

Comment: Spoken amidst an incomprehensible coughing fit

Comment: @Stu, if you want to post your comment about dirty hacks being possible while making your blood run cold (i feel the same about it), and t-sql not being a typical imperative language, I will mark it as the answer.

Thanks for all the input.

Comment: `sp_send_dbmail` is designed as an alert system for DBAs, not as a generalized mailing app. You should use a proper mailing solution instead.

Comment: @Charlieface it’s no MailChimp, but it’s built on ServiceBroker and is pretty robust.  So certainly not for customer engagement, but for enterprise-scale alerting it’s a reasonable solution.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Say what you like, but the logging is awful, and generating XHTML using SQL is pretty nasty. It is also missing many configuration options, and TLS can be annoying to get working. Even C# or Powershell would be far better.

Comment: @Charlieface Making tables look nice, adding signature logo's etc was a pain for sure, but I've had great results using sp_send_dbmail.  However, I'm open to alternative suggestions.  Creating a powershell script is something I understand.  When you say C#, are you suggesting creating an app in visual studio or something?  I am an IT manager but have a very small team and little support and there's an unlimited ever-expanding ocean of IT technology and resources which are a struggle to stay up to date on while engaged in the daily grind.  Definitely open to learning to improve my processes.

Comment: Yes you could do it in C# or Powershell. I'm sure there are libraries that could generate pretty HTML for you, and sending email is only a few lines of code (maybe more for robustness and logging). But it sounds like you need some kind of tool like PowerAutomate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be *possible* to implement a dirty hack such using `goto` - you *could* have your variable init section and jump to it with `goto` and have another variable to store a value to determine where to then jump back to, but I would *never* consider this an option for production code; T-Sql is not like a typical imperative language - if you need to repeat a block of variable assignments, then so be it.

Instead of a swathe of repeated similar local variables, perhaps consider a `#tempTable` with columns representing the repeated variables. Truncate it and populate it with 4 (or however many) rows to initialize on each use
with just an Id to represent each variable subscript; being a temp table you could even put this init code in its own procedure which would have visibility of the temp table.

Then code that would assign a variable can just update the table for row `n` and you can select the relevant column/row for building the final string.

Comment: Or a temp table with n rows and a cursor.